# Should I add Sandbox support to VFFiddle?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, css

I'm working on some updates to to  [VF Fiddle](https://vffiddle.herokuapp.com/). I want to gauge the interest in running fiddles in sandbox and get some feedback on the security concerns. Because fiddles are not reviewed they could potentially damage or leak information from a full-copy sandbox.
They were originally intended for Developer Edition Orgs. However, I appreciate that many users do not have DE orgs.

Also, I will need some beta-testers as I don't have a sandbox login I can use, please let me know if you're willing to help.

Thanks

Comment: This might be better asked in Meta, Heroku or Github. At a minimum, you'll want to provide a link for anyone to respond to if they're interested in beta testing as there's not a good means of contacting others within SF.SE.

Comment: I admit I didn't think this through completely yet, but when reading about vffiddle, I wondered if it would be possible to create 1 dedicated developer edition with a Site, so everybody can use the same environment (and recreate any scenario) without having to log in?

Comment: While I'd absolutely love to see VF Fiddle mature and gain support,  this site has a specific scope for specific questions and is not a general salesforce board.

Comment: Can I move it to meta?

Comment: I can't see a way to move the question and answer automagically :-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I'd like to see sandbox support in VF Fiddle.  The potential for leaking information means I must run it somewhere other than production.  If I need to get a DE to use VF Fiddle, I certainly will, but sandbox support would be convenient.

I am willing to beta test.